# data source configuration wizard issue Could not get column information for database object named

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and connecting to MySQL database through MySqlODBC 5.1 driver. The page is a reporting page (I'm using crystal report and devexpresss reporting tool).

I have successfully tested the ODBC connection to my MYSQL database using Data source Configuration wizard, and after creating connectionString I can see my database objects , i.e. Tables , Stored procedures, but when I select any table , it do not expand to show me columns and when i click on finish it gives me data source configuration wizard error message,

<`tyrepro`..`vendor`>
Could not get column information for database object named '`tyrepro`..`vendor`'

*vendor is table name here.

I tried connecting to system database and select table , but got same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i was able to solve this issue.
 The culprit was MYSQL ODBC 5.1 driver, instead i downloaded "dotConnect for MySQL" data provider and used it to connect MySQL.